# SQL Server Stored procedure declaring variable in different way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm just started using MSSQL and need to understand.

While I was reading few sample code that I might use in near future
found

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Set_LMS_BY_ERW] @UPA nvarchar(30) = NULL
```

Question is what's the difference between `@UPA` above
`Declare @count nvarchar(30)`?

Thank you

Comment: Usually parameters are placed between parenthesis for clarity: `( @UPA As nvarchar(30) = NULL,  ...)`, but SQL does not require it.

Comment: Since you say you are new to sql server I would suggest you stop the habit of prefixing your procedures with sp_ before it is too late. I personally do not like prefixes on object but if you use them you should avoid sp_. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Thanks Sean and RBarry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@UPA nvarchar(30) = NULL` is the procedure argument/parameter (in this case, an optional parameter though since it's being declared like that having `NULL` as the default value. So while calling procedure if you don't supply `@UPA`, it will assume `NULL`) that you need to supply while calling the procedure like

```
exec  [dbo].[SP_Set_LMS_BY_ERW] @UPA=N'test123'
```

whereas `Declare @count nvarchar(30)` is a local variable that's going to be use for some intermediary calculation or manipulation or to store some local data within your procedure body.

Comment: And in the context of a `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `DECLARE` would follow the `AS` keyword and be in the body of the procedure.